# Adding a view from a library project

Tags: android, libraries, custom-view

I have a project for which i wanted to implement a custom view.

I wrote the custom view in a library project, and included the project as a dependecy.

I declared the view in XML like this

if my library project package is com.lib.views

myView is

```
    <com.lib.views.CustomSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
    </com.lib.views.CustomSpinner>
```

However, when i run the app, the give class is not found.

What do i need to do to make it found ?

Comment: Is your library an external project or a JAR?

Comment: an external project, and it is in the dependency list

Comment: You can try to export it: Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export and check your library.

Comment: that option is not available

Comment: Then add the project as library first :)

Comment: i did that,strangely enough it does recognize other custom views i've written in this library, but not this one